# Do you know of some performances test of the different ways to get thread local storage in C++?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, thread-local

I'm doing a library that makes extensive use of a thread local variable. 
Can you point to some benchmarks that test the performances of the different ways to get thread local variables in C++:

- C++0x thread_local variables
- compiler extension (Gcc __thread, ...)
- boost::threads_specific_ptr
- pthread
- Windows
- ...

Does C++0x thread_local performs much better on the compilers providing it?

Comment: I haven't done any tests but I'd be surprised if they would be compiled to different things (with possible exception pthread<-->Windows) i.e. section of executable marked as thread local.

Comment: Any conclusion to this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `time.h`. Its your friend when testing performance stuff and nothing else is available.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a benchmark of the use in different contexts. Of course I can do it myself, but I would prefer to reuse one if it exists.
Maybe you are interested in Boost.Chrono :)

Answer (score 1):

These are typically implemented as a simple offset in an array in the thread's private memory space. So, accessing the thread specific variable `X`, of type `T`,

```
T y = X;
```

roughly translates to,

```
T y = *(T*)(cur_thread.local_tbl[key_X]);
```

which is too simple to expect a wide variation in performance between implementations. That said, if you find any such benchmarks, please follow up here.

Comment: The current Boost implementation is not so simple, as the key is the address of the thread_specific_pointer variable.
Compilers can now the keys at compile time, and can make some optimizations.
So I expect a wide variation between available implementations, that can be determinant to libraries that make a deep use of thread specific storage.